# Has Disney really succeeded in keeping this antagonist completely under wraps?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, solo-a-star-wars-story

I get this is to some degree runs afoul of the future works policy, but it's very unusual to be this close to the release of a movie and not have any idea about the plot or even who any of the bad guys are.

I.e. Who or what is this guy?

[image: The bad guy wears a fluffy looking top on the shoulders with a dark grey heavy looking helmet with only a thin horizontal slot to see out of surrounded by solves, some weapons are worn on the back; in the background we see 4 of their minions]

So to be clear, I'm asking if there really have been no credible leaks?   Am I wrong that no information is known at this juncture?

Comment: http://www.starwarsunderworld.com/2018/04/solo-trading-cards-reveal-new-details.html

Comment: Did people VTC because who the character is is subject to opinion or because what constitutes a credible leak is subject to opinion.   Because if it's the first, that's not the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Pure speculation**

[Dryden Vos](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dryden_Vos)

It is known that Dryden Vos is a crime lord, played by Paul Bettany in the film.

Or - **Enfys Nest**

[Secondary media](https://www.starwarsunderworld.com/2018/04/solo-trading-cards-reveal-new-details.html) has confirmed that the character featured promintently in the trailer is Enfys Nest. It seems reasonable to assume that this character is the alpha / champion / leader of the depicted group, and Han is likely set to combat her.

[image: The bad guy wears their ceremonial robes, tan and white patterned with a black fluffy cloak over the top that has a red inner layer. They also have a large clunky helmet on and wield a staff. They stand on the sandy floor with a dozen or so minions behind backing them up]

[image: View from Han's hip with his hand hovering over his holstered pistol, the background is blurred but we see the bad guy and minions from the image above waiting]

Comment: Thank you.   [Dryden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Dryden)?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Dryden: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Latimer_Dryden